# ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo ExitElement not animating in Windows 10 UWP project

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm attempting to use the ContinuumNavigationTransition effect in a Windows 10 UWP app. I can get the EntranceElement to correctly fly in when navigating pages, but the ExitElement never animates out.

As a repro case, I made a bare minimum app, with still no success. My code looks like the following:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView x:Name="TheList"
                ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind SomeItems}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"                                   
                                   ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsExitElement="True"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Content="Navigate" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public ObservableCollection<String> SomeItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
    {
        "Item 1!",
        "Item 2!"
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(SubPage));
    }
```

SubPage.xaml

```
<Page.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition>
                <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                    <ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo/>
                </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
            </NavigationThemeTransition>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Page.Transitions>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="I'm an entrance element!"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True"                   
                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                   Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
```

SubPage.xaml.cs

```
public SubPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SubPage_BackRequested; 
        }

        private void SubPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= SubPage_BackRequested;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe where you are going wrong is that you are using a button to navigate whereas Entrance elements and exit elements are used to kind of carry the context forward. So ideally you should navigate on listview item click.Code wise I couldn't see anything wrong and check this link it might be of some use. 
    http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/06/24/Page-transitions-and-animations-in-Windows-Phone-Runtime.aspx

Comment: Hm, no luck. Even changing it so that navigation happens in the ListViewItem's DataTemplate OnTapped doesn't work (nor does using the ListView ItemClick event).